# readAll() or readAllStandardOutput() is returning an empty string that too before execution

Tags: python, c++, qt

As defined in the title, these both functions are returning a empty string.
let me describe my scenerio, I am executing a python file which at last is printing a text, the text gets posted on Application Output after execution but the given output is not copied.
also my python script takes 30 to 40 seconds to execute but the readAll functions are executing just after loading the script.

my function which is executing the python script:

```
    QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QString path = "D:/DS Project/Treegramming";
    QString  command("py");
    QStringList params = QStringList() << "nlp.py";
    params << text;
    QProcess *process = new QProcess();
    process->startDetached(command, params, path);
    process->waitForFinished(30000);
    QByteArray ba = "";
    process->waitForReadyRead(30000);
    ba += process->readAllStandardOutput();
    qDebug() << ba ;
```

repeating again, qDebug() is giving empty output before the whole script is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the line...

```
process->startDetached(command, params, path);
```

Here you are actually calling the [static `startDetached` member](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) which has nothing to do with your newly created `QProcess`.  Hence you won't see any standard output/error.

Instead you should use the [non-static `start` member](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) with something like (untested)...

```
process->setWorkingDirectory(path);
process->start(command, params);
```